# MetaSearch sort ordered column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I have a model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'date_begin'
end
```

There is a sort link in a view file:

```
= sort_link @search, :date_begin
```

When I'm trying to order date_begin as DESC nothing happens because the SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY date_begin, date_begin DESC
```

How to make MetaSearch reorder this column? (I know that there is a "reorder" method in ActiveRecord but I don't know how to apply it to MetaSearch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [unscoped](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class) method when you decided to use `meta_search`:

```
@search = Event.unscoped.search(params[:search])
```

Comment: But I want to use scopes and default order by date and just reorder by date_begin column when user clicks on the "sort_link". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to use a default sort order, and didn't figure out any other way than to enforce a default order in the controller, not using any ordering scope in the model:

```
search = {"meta_sort" => "created_at.desc"}.merge(params[:search] || {})
@search = Photo.search(search)
```

The default sort order is created_at DESC, but it will be overwritten if a new sort order is received in the params. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
@search = if params[:q] && params[:q][:s]
  # Ransack sorting is applied - cancel default sorting
  Event.reorder(nil).search(params[:q])
else
  # Use default sorting
  Event.search(params[:q])
end
```

Benefits:

1) only cancels :order scope - useful if you have .where(:deleted_at => nil).order(:date_begin) default scope.

2) uses default ordering when Ransack sorting is not applied.